# UPDATE desde pyodbc: No localiza los registros a modificar

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

Al intentar hacer un

```
UPDATE articulos SET nombre=[id_articulo];
```

desde python, utilizando pyobdc, obtengo el mensaje de error:

> [HY000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] La clave de
>   búsqueda no se encontró en ningún registro. (-1601) (SQLExecDirectW)

El resto de UPDATE los realiza correctamente y sí que hay registros que cumplen ese criterio. Esta misma consulta desde Access funciona correctamente. ¿Este paquete puede tener algún tipo de limitación para actualizar registros en bloque por ODBC?

El objetivo de la consulta de actualización de datos es que el campo `nombre` valga lo mismo que el campo `id_articulo` y, así, dejar disponibles los nombres de artículo que ya no utilizo. El campo `nombre` está indexado sin duplicados.

Los corchetes en `[id_articulo]` no tienen relación con la notación de arrays, es como Access identifica los campos.

Hasta el momento he probado con:

```
UPDATE articulos SET nombre=Str([id_articulo]) WHERE 1;

UPDATE articulos SET nombre=Str(id_articulo) WHERE 1;

UPDATE articulos SET nombre=Str([articulos.id_articulo]) WHERE 1;
```

Comment: HOla david, me puedes ayudar a ver que contiene tu array [id_articulo] ?

Comment: HOla david, si pero creo que debe estar formado de esta manera array[id_articulo] y si no mal recuerdo tiene que estar de esta manera UPDATE articulos SET nombre='array[id_articulo];' WHERE variable = identificador;

Comment: UPDATE articulos SET nombre=Str(id_articulo) WHERE id_articulo = Str(id_articulo); recuerda que como es indexado y es unico no puedes hacer un cambio en cascado, solo que quites la indexacion y pruebes de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Tras renunciar a la actualización en bloque de todos los registros e implementar un bucle para actualizarlos uno a uno, he detectado que, por algún tipo de fallo en la base de datos que detallo en la pregunta [Compactar y reparar base de datos Access desde SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289569), existe un registro en concreto que el motor de la base de datos no consigue localizar y, por tanto, tampoco modificar. Cuando lo excluyo, actualiza todos los registros correctamente:

```
UPDATE articulos SET nombre=[id_articulo] WHERE id_articulo<>22445;
```

Con esta solución no resuelvo el problema, simplemente lo evito. Espero que, a falta de una solución mejor, ayude a quien se encuentre en una situación similar. El problema estaba en la base de datos, no en el `SQL` ni en el `pyodbc`.

Para actualizar los registros uno a uno, detectando a los que producen fallo, he hecho uso del tratamiento de excepciones de python:

```
try:
  cursor.execute("UPDATE ...")
except:
  print('Registro defectuoso')
```