# Compactar y reparar base de datos Access desde SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

No consigo eliminar un registro de mi base de datos

> [HY000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] La clave de
>   búsqueda no se encontró en ningún registro. (-1601) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Esta instrucción lo localiza perfectamente:

```
    SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id_articulo=27151;
```

Pero ésta no:

```
    DELETE FROM tabla WHERE id_articulo=27151;
```

Había pensado en compactar y reparar la base de datos a ver si se resuelve, pero sólo tengo acceso por ODBC y no consigo localizar el comando que realice esta función.

Afortunadamente un `TRUNCATE` funciona correctamente, así que siempre puedo duplicar la tabla y eliminar la defectuosa.

Comment: El comando TRUNCATE fue la solución entonces?

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz, preferiría encontrar un comando similar al REPAIR de Mysql para Access aunque, si no encuentro nada, podría llegar a arreglarme con el TRUNCATE

Comment: ¿Has probado con `DELETE tabla.*, tabla.[id_articulo]
FROM tabla
WHERE (((tabla.[id_articulo])=27151))`?